# Is there documentation for objects returned by WP_Query?

Tags: wp-query

I'm running a cusotm `WP_Query` to get a handful of posts based on some parameters. Once I have the posts and I'm looping over them, I need to extract certain metadata elements, such as a list of tags for the post.

I see there's a function [`get_the_tags`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_tags/) for fetching an array of "tag objects", but I'm not seeing any references to where those are documented (i.e. what properties/methods do the tag objects have?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tag objects returned by `get_the_tags()` use [`WP_term`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_term/) class. You can see this by inspecting the function's source. The class is mentioned on the last line of the comment.

```
function get_the_tags( $id = 0 ) {

    /**
     * Filters the array of tags for the given post.
     *
     * @since 2.3.0
     *
     * @see get_the_terms()
     *
     * @param WP_Term[] $terms An array of tags for the given post.
     */
    return apply_filters( 'get_the_tags', get_the_terms( $id, 'post_tag' ) );
}
```